# Clarification about equality of Fourier series.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Say you have a function, $f(x)$, with period $2\pi$, and say you have computed the Fourier coefficients in the standard way, i.e.,

$$a_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) dx,$$
$$a_k = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\cos(nx) dx,$$
$$b_k = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\sin(nx) dx.$$

Then, according to my notes, we say that 
$$f(x) \approx a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n \cos(nx) + b_n \sin(nx)).$$

My question is, how would one know if $f(x)$ actually equals this Fourier expansion, instead of just "corresponding" with it? Is there some theorem we can use, instead of actually just summing the expansion, which may be too difficult to do in certain scenarios?

Comment: You are asking a very standard question in Fourier analysis. To answer this question, we need to first make precise what you mean by equals, i.e. in what sense is the Fourier series equals the function.

Comment: Equals as in, coincides. Just the usual way. For example, I am trying to show that $\frac{\pi-x}{2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$.

Comment: There's a whole boatload of convergence theorems for Fourier series. There is pointwise convergence, Césaro convergence, $L^p$ convergence, and so on. You might look at some of [these answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=[fourier-series]+convergence). To summarize, the Fourier series does not converge pointwise in general, even for continuous functions. But if the function has a continuous derivative, it does. (This condition can be relaxed quite a bit.)

Comment: So, since my function is continuous, and has a continuous derivative, this is enough to guarantee equality? Do you know if such a result has a name?

Comment: I don't know that the theorem has a name, other than “Pointwise convergence of Fourier series”. It's hard to beat the proof given by Chernoff in *The American Mathematical Monthly* back in 1980 ([doi:10.2307/2321220](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2321220)).

Comment: If you plot (say, using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+sin(n*x)%2Fn+from+n%3D1+to+10))  a partial sum of the Fourier series you provide, you'll see that it's only converging to $(\pi-x)/2$ on the interval $(0,2\pi)$. (FYI: In order to reproduce this series, you'll need to have this as your interval of integration as well rather than $(-\pi,\pi)$.) The behavior at $x=0$ is especially worth noting.

Comment: Ah, I had failed to notice the example given in your comment above, as @Semiclassical noted. What you'll see at any discontinuity is known as the [Gibbs phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon). Your function is in fact *not* continuous, when turned into a $2\pi$-periodic function. But you'll have pointwise convergence everywhere except at the discontinuity, by the theorem proved by Chernoff in his paper (and well known much earlier).

Comment: Ah. For our sake, we only defined the function on $(0, 2\pi)$ actually, I assume to avoid this problem. Basically, I said the function and its derivative are continuous on this interval. That should be it, right? Our domain avoids these problems? Or, do I still need to turn my function into a $2-\pi$ periodic function to do the whole Fourier analysis thing?

Comment: In that case, yes: As $n\to\infty$, your series will converge pointwise to $(\pi-x)/2$ for any $x\in(0,2\pi)$. The point, more or less, is that that restriction is sharp: If you take $x=0$, then the Fourier series is identically zero whereas the function of interest evaluates to $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many standard results that apply. Extend your function periodically from $(-\pi,\pi]$ to all of $\mathbb{R}$. For this extended function $f$,

1. **(Jordan)** If $f$ is of bounded variation on $[a,b]$, then $f$ has left- and right-hand limits at every point of $(a,b)$, and the Fourier series converges pointwise everywhere in $(a,b)$ to the mean of the left- and right-hand limits.
2. **(Dirichlet)** If $f$ has left- and right-hand limits at $x$, and has left- and right-hand derivatives at $x$, then $f$ converges to the mean of the left- and right-hand limits of $f$ at $x$.
3. **(Fejer)** If $f$ has left- and right-hand limits at $x$, then the running average of the Fourier series at $x$ converges to the mean of the left- and right-hand limits of $f$. That is, if
   $$
           S_n = a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx),
   $$
   then the sequence of running averages,
   $$
        S_0, \frac{S_0+S_1}{2},\frac{S_0+S_1+S_2}{3},\cdots,
   $$
   converges to the mean of the left- and right-hand limits of $f$. No further smoothness is required.
4. **(Dini)** If there is a number $L$ such that the following holds for some small $\epsilon$, then the Fourier series for $f$ at $x$ converges to $L$:
   $$
          \int_{0}^{\epsilon}\frac{1}{u}\left|\frac{f(x-u)+f(x+u)}{2}-L\right|du < \infty
   $$
5. **(Carleson)** If $f$ is Lebesgue measurable and square integrable on $[-\pi,\pi]$, then the Fourier series for $f$ converges almost everywhere to $f$.